# How do I change this import into a require?

Tags: javascript, node.js

`import { Client as Hypixel, getNetworkLevel } from "@zikeji/hypixel";`
I want to change this import into require. Please go easy on me, I'm pretty new to coding.

Comment: look to document that has example like what you need  const { Client } = require("@zikeji/hypixel");

Answer (score 3):

```js
const { Client: Hypixel, getNetworkLevel } = require("@zikeji/hypixel");
```